# Exclude certain response model fields from Enunciate docs

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, javadoc, enunciate

**Problem**: I have some java models being used both for request and response body on some endpoints. The thing is, on a specific request, I don't want to show all fields from that model; also, on the response, maybe I want to show completely different fields from that same model.

**Question**: Is this possible using Enunciate ? Or we just have to use the same model composition on both request and response ?

I've looked into this and found the [Enunciate API Facets](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Enunciate+API+Facets). However, haven't figured out how to exclude only *some* fields from the model. Other than this specific feature, for now I've found Enunciate to be extremely useful and nice to use. It also produces quite good looking docs. :)

Comment: Do you want to change the documentation or the real response? For latter you could use Jacksons [JSON Views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews).

Comment: I'd want to change the documentation only, but I will have a look at your suggestion anyway, might be helpful. Can you think of any other alternative ? I just want to explore all the possibilities (or at least the most used). Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: For hiding internal fields you could map/clone/copy to a new object where the internal fields are set to null and tell your serializer to ignore null-values.

Comment: I've looked into JSONViews, but I'm not using a serializer, just JAX-RS annotations. From those annotations Enunciate constructs the docs, so I'm not really solving the initial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Enunciate's documentation engine isn't that sophisticated. There's no way to configure Enunciate to document which fields of a model should be populated based for a specific request (or response).

It would be nice feature though. Why don't you [open up a JIRA issue](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE) so the request can get tracked?

Comment: Hello Ryan. Firstly, thank you for your answer, it's nice to have an official answer on this matter. Secondly, I would gladly open up an issue, but I cannot seem to sign up on your JIRA subdomain: "Not a member? To request an account, please contact your JIRA administrators." And I could not find any means of achieving this. Could you please provide some directions in order for me to sign up on your subdomain ? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any chance you could open up a ticket instead ? Or give some indications on how to open an account on your subdomain ?